# How add invoice fee on order reporting

Tags: magento-1.7, payment

I have created own payment gateway extension. My problem is this I have to add extra invoice fee in orders. I am able to add custom invoice fee on checkout page updated total accordingly but I am unable to configure magento to show invoice fee on order detail pages from user account and admin account on order detail pages i can see gross total with invoice fee but unable to see invoice fee in anywhere

please help me to do this task

Comment: What modules do you have installed? It might be some module you need to Depend in your module. And i have also found that you need lowercases in for example <sales_email_order_items> <reference name="order_totals"> <block name="billmateinvoice_fee" type="billmateinvoice/order_totals_fee" before="tax"/> </reference>
</sales_email_order_items> Both Magento 1.8 and 1.9 complains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think your config.xml should missing layout configurations like following

```
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <billmateinvoice module="Billmate_BillmateInvoice">
                <file>billmateinvoice.xml</file>
            </billmateinvoice>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
```

and same as for frontend

```
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <billmateinvoice module="Billmate_BillmateInvoice">
                <file>billmateinvoice.xml</file>
            </billmateinvoice>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

and this is following `billmateinvoice.xml` for frontend

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<sales_order_print>
    <reference name="order_totals">
        <block name="billmateinvoice_fee" type="BillmateInvoice/order_totals_fee" before="tax"/>
    </reference>
</sales_order_print>

<sales_order_view>
    <reference name="order_totals">
        <block name="billmateinvoice_fee" type="BillmateInvoice/order_totals_fee" before="tax"/>
    </reference>
</sales_order_view>

<sales_order_invoice>
    <reference name="invoice_totals">
        <block name="billmateinvoice_fee" type="BillmateInvoice/invoice_totals_fee" before="tax"/>
    </reference>
</sales_order_invoice>

<sales_order_printinvoice>
    <reference name="invoice_totals">
        <block name="billmateinvoice_fee" type="BillmateInvoice/invoice_totals_fee" before="tax"/>
    </reference>
</sales_order_printinvoice>

<sales_email_order_items>
    <reference name="order_totals">
        <block name="billmateinvoice_fee" type="BillmateInvoice/order_totals_fee" before="tax"/>
    </reference>
</sales_email_order_items>

<sales_email_order_invoice_items>
    <reference name="invoice_totals">
        <block name="billmateinvoice_fee" type="BillmateInvoice/invoice_totals_fee" before="tax"/>
    </reference>
</sales_email_order_invoice_items>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to override
collect() and fetch() functions in

Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract class, if u aren't sure about how to do that refer [this link](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total)

Comment: no its not working i have used this article to create extra fee its only work on checkout page not on order pages